# ARC-Type conversion causes compiler error

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, type-conversion

i am having a problem in type conversion in ARC environment.if anyone would be kind enough to address it as well:

when i used this line of code:

`OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching((CFDictionaryRef) CFBridgingRetain(attributeQuery), (CFTypeRef*)&attributeResult);`

then i am having error :

`cast of an indirect pointer to an objective C pointer to 'CFTypeRef *' is disallowed with ARC.`

Please suggest me any way to ressolve this.. 
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are using a NSDictionary for attributeResult instead of a CFDictionary. Try this and it should work (I'm using the same code):

```
CFMutableDictionaryRef outDictionary = NULL;
if (!SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)tempQuery, (CFTypeRef *)&outDictionary) == noErr)
...
} else {
  // load the saved data from Keychain.
  keychainItemData = [self secItemFormatToDictionary:(__bridge NSDictionary *)outDictionary];
}
if(outDictionary) CFRelease(outDictionary);
```